# Allow Null only if another column has a particular value

Tags: sql

I am trying to allow Null for some of the columns only if some particular column has a certain value. How do I do that? So lets say I create a table where intially I want all the columns to be NOT NULL but if a there is a certain value in the `type` column, I want to allow `R_Min` columns to be NULL and `R_max` column to be null.

```
create table Range(
OptionID int,
IndexID int,
PRIMARY KEY(OptionID, IndexID), 
Type varchar(255)NOT NULL,
Name varchar(255)NOT NULL,
RType varchar(255)NOT NULL,
R_Min decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
R_Max decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
R2_Min decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
R2_Max decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
Boundary decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `check(type= 'somevalue' or R_Min is not null)`

Comment: check constraint, no need for triggers

Comment: You need to specify the RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the column as nullable. Add a check constraint to only allow NULL for certain Type value.

```
create table Range(
...
Type varchar(255)NOT NULL,
...
R_Min decimal(19,6),
...
check (type = 'certainvalue' or R_Min is not null)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of NOT NULL

ex:

```
create table Range(
OptionID int,
IndexID int,
PRIMARY KEY(OptionID, IndexID), 
Type varchar(255)NOT NULL,
Name varchar(255)NOT NULL,
RType varchar(255)NOT NULL,
R_Min decimal(19,6),
R_Max decimal(19,6),
R2_Min decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
R2_Max decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
Boundary decimal(19,6)NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: I dont want to do that cause for all other types I want it to be Not null

Comment: all other types will still be nn

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is made by so called `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint
- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Specific syntax quirks and limitations might depend upon server vendor and even specific version of it. So read the docs.

But the generic idea is like that:

```
ALTER TABLE Range
ADD CHECK
  ( ((r_min IS NOT NULL) and (r_max IS NOT NULL))
     or (type = 'abcdcba') )
```

Of course the unconditional `NOT NULL` clauses should be removed from both `R_Min` and `R_Max` columns in the table declaration then.